# get result from phtml file to html

Tags: magento2, javascript, html, convert, block-html

I have below code (which is at .phtml page) which echo store view selected and i want to take that value which is echo by below code and display it in an html page. please help how to do that. thanks.

```
<?php
    $ObjectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $storeManager = $ObjectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');

    $selectedStore = $storeManager->getStore()->getName();
?>
```

Comment: you can a phtml file in html using layout. if you can write your html code in phtml file and call this phtml file in your html

Comment: How can i get those result in html using layout? @Mehran

Comment: i'm failing to get store name from phtml to html file using layout. i have able to acho out the name of the store in phtml file but i'm failing to echo it on html file under shipping method options